# How can I tell if a number is a multiple of four using only the logic operator AND?

Tags: assembly, binary, bit-manipulation

I'm messing with assembly language programming and I'm curious how I could tell if a number is a multiple of 4 using the logic operator AND?

I know how to do it using "div" or "remainder" instructions but I'm trying to do this with bit manipulation of number/word.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I'm using MIPs but a Language agnostic answer is fine.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, to detect if a number is a multiple of another, you simply need to do `x MOD y`. If the result is `0`, then it is an even multiple.

It is also true that for every `y` that is a power of `2`, `(x MOD y)` is equivalent to `(x AND (y - 1))`.

Therefore:

```
IF (x AND 3) == 0 THEN
    /* multiple of 4 */
```

**EDIT:**

ok, you want to know **why** `(x MOD y) == (x AND (y - 1))` when `y` is a power of 2. I'll do my best to explain.

Basically, if a number is a power of 2, then it has a single bit set (since binary is base 2). This means that all of the lower bits are unset. So for example: `16 == 10000b, 8 == 1000b`, etc.

If you subtract 1 from any of these values. You end up with the bit that was set being unset and all bits below it being set.

`15 = 01111b, 7 = 0111b`, etc. So basically it is creates a mask which can be used to test if the any of the lower bits were set. I hope that was clear.

**EDIT:** Bastien Léonard's comment covers it well too:

> if you divide (unsigned) by 4, you
>   shift two bits to the right. Thus the
>   remainder is those two bits, which get
>   lost when you divide. 4 - 1 = 11b,
>   that is, a mask that yields the two
>   rightmost bits when you AND it with a
>   value.

**EDIT:** see this page for possibly clearer explanations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two#Fast_algorithm_to_check_if_a_positive_number_is_a_power_of_two.

It covers detecting powers of 2 and using AND as a fast modulo operation if it is a power of 2.

Comment: Yea, i was explaining why you can AND with y -1, to get the same value as MOD y.

Comment: @tvanfosson: thanks for the rollback, was about to do that myself after your comment in the other post :).

Comment: @Evan Teran, I see how you say that they are equivalent but I still don't see why it would be y - 1?

Comment: @Mithrax: if you divide (unsigned) by 4, you shift two bits to the right. Thus the remainder is those two bits, which get lost when you divide. 4 - 1 = 11b, that is, a mask that yields the two rightmost bits when you AND it with a value.

Comment: @Bastien: goo way to word it, added to my answer.

Comment: Write x as an expansion in powers of 2 and assume y = 2^k for some k. Then write: x = (\Sigma_{m=k}^{\infty} c_m * 2^m) + Remainder. The first term is a multiple of y, while 'Remainder' < y. So, x mod y is equivalent to 'Remainder'. But this is just the bit pattern x & y-1.

Answer (score 5):

(x & 3) == 0

W.r.t. assembly language, use TST if available, otherwise AND, and check the zero flag.

Comment: @John -- yes it is 0 is the product of 0 x 4. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_(mathematics)

Answer (score 3):

In x86 assembly:

```
    test eax, 3
    jnz not_multiple_of_4

    ; action to be taken if EAX is a multiple of 4

not_multiple_of_4:
    ; ...
```

Answer (score 1):

A number is a multiple of 4 if its lower 2 bits are 0, so you can simply shift the number right twice and check shifted bits for 0.

Comment: Most machines only keep track of the last bit shifted out, or MIPS that the OP is asking about doesn't have flags at all.  If you wanted to use a shift, you'd *left* shift by `32-2` to shift out all the *other* bits, leaving only the low 2 bits which might be non-zero.  Or better, isolate them with AND, like `x & 3`