# find if a number is divisible by 8 - using bit shifting operators

Tags: bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I was recently asked during an interview, using just bit shift operators, write some code that would tell you if a number is divisible by 8, apparently the code is very short - does anyone have a clue?

Note: if you aren't required to use shifts, you'd test the low `n` bits for being all-zero with a mask like `x&7 == 0`, or more generally 
`x & ((1UL << n) - 1) == 0`.  [How can I tell if a number is a multiple of four using only the logic operator AND?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748673/how-can-i-tell-if-a-number-is-a-multiple-of-four-using-only-the-logic-operator-a)

Comment: Hint, right shift is the same as divide by 2

Comment: @SteveKuo in C, only for positive integers

Comment: and 8 is 2 * 2 * 2 ;)

Comment: @ouah there are sign-preserving right shifts. I believe the C syntax is `num >>> 3`.

Comment: @SergeyL. - that's Java syntax. In C and C++ there is no sign-preserving right shift of a negative value; a right-shift of a negative number has implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: @PeteBecker Cheers, I knew I saw it somewhere. I do know there is an x86 instruction that does sign-preserving bit shifts.

Comment: sounds like an amazon interview question

Comment: return !(x & (8-1));

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With any integer represented in binary the remainder of division by any power of two is simply the value of the bits of lower order so `0b11001110` divided by `0b1000` has remainder `0b110`. So in order to check for divisibility by 8 you need to check if the three low order bits are all zero:

```
if (((x >> 3) << 3) == x)
  divisibleBy8 = true;
```

Right shifting clears the bottom three bits before the left shift restores the magnitude and then compare to the original number.

As others have pointed out, if you know the bit width of the integer you can do this

```
if (!(x<<29))
  divisibleby8 = true;
```

Replace that 29 by 61 for 64-bit integers, etc. Apparently in Java you can do this:

```
if ((x << -3) != 0)
  divisibleby8 = true;
```

Because negative shifts such as `-3` are interpreted as `bit_width - 3` and it will work with both 32- and 64-bit integers.

(You don't need all the brackets, I've included for clarity)

**Just for completeness**

These are all pretty bad ways to test for divisibility by 8. Doing `if !(x & 7)` is clearer and almost certainly as fast or faster.

Comment: Is that not "divisible by 4"?

Comment: you know an answer similar to this was in my head, i did not mention my thoughts on this because i thought it might be wrong, why do i hold back?? Let me confirm this works

Comment: @godzilla because `1 << 3 == 8`

Comment: 2 to the power 3 is 8. A number is divisible by eight if and only if the lowest value three bits are zero.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas - surely more compact, but incorrect... (saw your edit  -> still machine dependant)

Comment: thanks Jack that clears things up, i will brush up my bit shifting skills, it  was one of those questions which could have been a life changer but not this time, i will be ready for it next time mind you :)

Comment: Hmm... this relies on comparing two numbers, and comparing (i.e. substraction) is not a bit shifting operation in the literal sense.

Answer (score 9):

```
int num;

if(!(num & 7)) {
     // num divisible by 8
}
```

or

```
if(! (num << 29) ) { // assuming num is 32 bits
    // num divisible by 8
}
```

Comment: @PeterLawrey Question bears C tag, It's valid C. You are right for java.

Answer (score 4):

In Java, without knowing if the type is `long` or `int` you can do this trick

```
if((x << -3) != 0)
```

This will shift by 29 or 61 bits as appropriate for that type. It will only be true if the lower three bits are 0.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is undefined (or implementation defined, or some other "do not do this if you want code to always work on any platform"), so probably won't necessarily work.

Comment: @MatsPetersson It is defined and will work on all JVMs whether 32-bit or 64-bit.  Java tends to define all it's edge cases, unlike some of the older languages. ;)

Comment: Sorry, my point was that "this only works in certain circumstances in other languages than Java".

Comment: @MatsPetersson It's undefined behavior in C.

Comment: I think, JLS3 15.19 can be interpreted that way. "It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & with the mask value 0x1f." That makes this the (only?) correct answer.

Comment: By the way, Java makes this operation [for normal values] slower [unless compiler can sort it out] by defining "edge cases" such as this, where C/C++ makes it undefined [that doesn't mean "it won't do what you expect", but that it MAY NOT do what you expect - in particular, it will end up shifting 61 bits on a 32-bit number on a PowerPC [I think that was an example used previously for similar question], but will "work" on x86].

Comment: @MatsPetersson If that is true, it's a bug in the JVM which should be fixed at some point.  You can't protect yourself from bugs in basic operations completely.

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood. I expect the JVM does it "correctly" in the sense that it is defined. But the C/C++ solution is undefined so that you don't have to have a "y << (x & bits_in(y)-1)`, adding an extra and operation on all shifts that doesn't have a constant [obviously, for a constant, the compiler can sort it anyway].

Answer (score 2):

```
if (x & ((1 << 3)-1) == 0)
```

Or, if you really want to use shifs:

```
if (x == ((x >> 3) << 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way to check for n’s divisibility by 9 is to do n%9.
Another method is to sum the digits of n. If sum of digits is multiple of 9, then n is multiple of 9. 
The above methods are not bitwise operators based methods and require use of ‘%’ and ‘/’. The bitwise operators are generally faster than modulo and division operators. Following is a bitwise operator based method to check divisibility by 9.

you should check this link 
http://www.firmcodes.com/check-number-multiple-9-using-bitwise-operators/

Answer (score 0):

`x << (32-3) == 0` for an `int`; `x << (64-3) == 0L` for a `long`.

Comment: Both expressions trigger undefined behavior in C.

Comment: @ouah I believe most C programs make extensive use of undefined behvaiour.

Answer (score 0):

**For simplicity's sake**

If you want to find out if any given integer N is multiple of X, being X a power of 2, just do:

```
    public static boolean isMultipleOfpowerOf2(int n, int x) {
    if((n&(x-1))==0){
       return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Why this work?

Consider X = 8;

```
8:        1000*
9:        1001
10:       1010
11:       1011
12:       1100
13:       1101
14:       1110
15:       1111***
16:      10000*
17:      10001
18:      10010
19:      10011
20:      10100
21:      10101
22:      10110
23:      10111***
24:      11000*
```

Now you can see clearly, that any multiple of 8 doesn't use the 3* right bits, and this is true for all power of 2.
You can see that X-1, 7, uses all of those bits***.

Now the rest is easy you can just mask out all the other bits using &(X-1), and if the answer is zero then you have a multiple.

```
N & (X-1) with  N = 9, X=8

N(9)    = 1001
X(8-1)  = 0111
N&(X-1) = 0001  this case is != 0

N(16)   = 10000
X(8-1)  = 00111
N&(X-1) = 00000  this time is == 0, it is a multiple.
```

More on this can be found in this really good article:
[Using Bitwise Operators to Work With Colors](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-bitwise-operators--active-11301)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (((x >> 3) << 3) == x)
    divisibleBy8 = true;
```

This would fail for the input 0 (zero)

Answer (score -4):

```
static boolean divisibleBy8(int num) {
    return (number & 7) == 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not only using bit shifts

Comment: ok ok, wasn't sure how much emphasized the "shift" was. Some people tend to confuse the terms. On the plus side, it works and it's the fastest solution. ;-)

Comment: How can "bit shift" mean anything else?

Comment: In that "bitwise" was actually meant, just not expressed precisely.